# In testing with Elixir, can the dB connection assigned to a GenServer be reassigned to the testing one?

Tags: testing, elixir, sandbox, ecto

My system has an app under an umbrella which starts up several GenServers, which on init make some dB calls, and thus get their own connection.

The problem is that in my tests of a controller where I have inserted some records into the dB, the controller makes a call to one of those GenServers, which then does some more dB queries.  But since it is a different sandbox, it does not see the records.

I am looking for a solution in general that would allow existing, running GenServers to use the same sandbox as the test.  I would greatly appreciate any ideas.  I tried adding the following right after the sandbox checkout in the test setup, but didn't help:

```
Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox.allow(MyApp.Repo, self(), Some.GenServer)
```

Comment: You could not run these tests asynchronously.

Comment: The tests are not running async.

Comment: Actually, now I am not sure.  There is no `async: true`, but does it default to that for `Phoenix.ConnTest`?  Having hard time finding info on that.

Comment: Then without seeing your code, it will be hard to debug. Because if the tests are run synchronously, it should work. Does your `setup` look this [this](https://gist.github.com/ankhers/56df26d14ddede86522b621c2a00138c)?

Comment: Minus lines 4 and 6, yes, exactly like that.

Answer (score 0):

The only working solution I found was to allow the GenServer to be started with an alternate name, starting it up thus using the same sandbox db connection as the test, having my controller use this differently named version, and shutting it down right before the end of the test.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that I ended up with the same issue.
My solution was to keep the default Phoenix settings, and terminate and restart my process before each test, like this:

```
setup(%{conn: conn}) do
    Supervisor.terminate_child(Some.Supervisor, Some.GenServer)
    Supervisor.restart_child(Some.Supervisor, Some.GenServer)
    {:ok, conn: conn}
end
```

Tests SHOULD NOT be async: true